# Play video from URL on Lollipop

Tags: android, video, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to open an .mp4 video from an URL like this

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri data = Uri.parse("https://yaddayadda/video.mp4");
    intent.setDataAndType(data, "video/*");


    if (intent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

This doesn't work on Lollipop when I try to open the video using the Google Photos app (on Nexus, that's the only option). On Kitkat and other versions, the Photos works, only on Lollipop it doesn't.

Does any one knows how to play the video on Lollipop using the Photos App?

Comment: Please explain what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: The google Photos app open and there is a message saying that I can't play that video. That only occurs on Lollipop, on Kitkat, the video plays.

Comment: Then there is not much you can do about it, other than perhaps try `video/mp4` instead of `video/*`.

Answer (score 0):

To View Video in your activity from an link use this code :

```
// Declare variables
ProgressDialog pDialog;
VideoView videoview;

// Insert your Video URL
String VideoURL = "http://<video-url>";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the layout from video_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.videoview_main);
    // Find your VideoView in your video_main.xml layout
    videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
    // Execute StreamVideo AsyncTask

    // Create a progressbar
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(VideoViewActivity.this);
    // Set progressbar title
    pDialog.setTitle("Video");
    // Set progressbar message
    pDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    // Show progressbar
    pDialog.show();

    try {
        // Start the MediaController
        MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                VideoViewActivity.this);
        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
        // Get the URL from String VideoURL
        Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
        videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
        videoview.setVideoURI(video);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    videoview.requestFocus();
    videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        // Close the progress bar and play the video
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            videoview.start();
        }
    });

}
```

If you don't have activity to play video and want to play in external player you can use this code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private Button btn;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://ur URL"), "video/*");

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"));
    }

}
```

}